# Change iOS Simulator Device Name

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator

I'm working on a big project with many view controllers. Progression through these views depends on data being filled in on lengthy forms.

In my not-so-clever way i'm autofilling data so that i can speed through to the current feature I'm working on. I was using a conditional like this...

```
if(
   [[[UIDevice currentDevice] name] hasPrefix:@"Rob"] ||
   [[[UIDevice currentDevice] name] hasPrefix:@"iPad Simulator"]
   )
{
    self.label.text = @"xxx";
    ...
}
```

...this worked great because I could test both on my iPad and in the simulator. Now the client wants to also be able to test on their simulator, so I can't leave my autofill in. I'm thinking the simplest solution would be to just change the name of the simulator.

In Settings.app on the simulator, it's not editable. I also haven't seen then text "iPad Simulator" or "Simulator" show up in any files in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1. I've done searches on setting plist properties, but no luck.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Very strange way for testing purposes, you should use `if(DEBUG) { ... }`

Comment: @Kashiv, I'm working in a team and not everyone needs or wants these autofilled in values. I checked and there also doesn't appear to be a way to set these compiler constants per user either. So putting logic in DEBUG blocks would still make all of my testing bit show for everyone (although that is the approach I originally opted for). Finally, I am putting #warnings around all of my testing blocks and as a last pass I'll delete them all when we're ready to do final testing.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to check if it's running the iPhone Simulator by checking the model rather than the name of the current device. Something like the following should do:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone Simulator"]) {
    // Run for iPhone simulator
}
```

**Note**: You'll need to use "iPad Simulator" for when you use the iPad Simulator

Also, your current code with hasPrefix is not secure at all. Rob is a common name so if someone else has a device with the name of their device beginning with Rob then it'll expose your test information. I highly suggest you just target this autocomplete for the simulator only

Comment: Hi Suhail, thanks for the answer. I can already tell it's running in the Simulator, but I want to change the name of my Simulator and then write a conditional based off that new name. Also, although the hasPrefix approach isn't ideal, this is for a enterprise distribution app and we'll have control over the device names, so it's not an issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new class and put your loading logic there.

After that, call this class from your delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

With this, you can comment the above call whenever you want or better, check if the data is already loaded and ignore it.

Comment: I like this approach for keeping everything tidy and may still use it, but I don't think it helps towards the goal. Thanks!